# How to override a method?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I am trying make a word in python where it prints out the movement, sound, and habitat of a animal currently I have the code below:

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self._name = name

    def sound(self):
        raise Exception("You have not overridden my sound yet!")

    def move(self):
        raise Exception("You have not overridden my movement yet!")

    def habitat(self):
        raise Exception("You have not overridden my habitat yet!")


class fish(Animal):
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name=Animal.__init__(name)
    def sound(self):
        return (f'{self.name} says blub blub')
    def movement(self):
        return (f'{self.name} is swimming')
    def habitat(self):
        return (f'{self.name} is an Aquatic Animal')

a=fish('nemo')
print(a.sound())
```

I am not allowed to edit the Animal parent class. I was hoping to have an output of :

```
nemo says blub blub
```

How do I go with this? Thank you for the help!

Comment: `__init` should be `__init__`

Comment: However `self.name=Animal.__init__(name)` doesn't make any sense, `__init__` doesn't return anything. Why are you doing this?

Comment: @Stael, nice catch there! Now the code raises a 

self.name=Animal.__init__(name)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'

I don't get it, I have an argument name right there.

Comment: @Monsi that isn't how you do inheritance, you should call `super()` to get the parent class, not define a property of your subclass as an instance of the super class.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I am not sure if it correct, but I did that because I would like to call it in other methods as you can see I called it in sound, movement, and habitat. I am really new in python, trying to learn the kinks

Comment: Why did you override `__init__` ?! There's no need to do that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this works

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self._name = name

    def sound(self):
        raise Exception("You have not overridden my sound yet!")

    def move(self):
        raise Exception("You have not overridden my movement yet!")

    def habitat(self):
        raise Exception("You have not overridden my habitat yet!")


class fish(Animal):
    def __init__(self,name):
        super().__init__(name)
        self.name = self._name
    def sound(self):
        return (f'{self.name} says blub blub')
    def movement(self):
        return (f'{self.name} is swimming')
    def habitat(self):
        return (f'{self.name} is an Aquatic Animal')

a=fish('nemo')
print(a.sound())
```

i fixed your `__init__` typo, and i think what you're trying to do is init the superclass, so i did that in the init of `fish`

you're using `self.name` in your methods so i set that in the init too, although i think the better way is to use `self._name` which you inherit from `Animal`

edit: as someone pointed out, if you're doing that (using self._name) then you actually don't need to overwrite the `__init__` method at all, the one in `Animal` will work fine.

Comment: Hi thank you for this but may I ask what '_name' does and what is its difference with 'name'?

Comment: it's just a naming difference. by convention variable that start with `_` are designed not to be used by anything outside the object (for example you don't call `Fish.__init__(name)`, you call `Fish(name)`). They're just different properties within the objects, and if the `Animal` class is using `_name` it makes sense that you use it too rather than defining a `name` as well.

Comment: also by convention all classes are capitalised, to distinguish from instances (objects) of that class, so `nemo = Fish('nemo')` or `a_fish = Fish('nemo')`

Comment: ohhh, okay I think I get it now, Thanks for your help! One last thing why it is better to call super() rather than just calling 'Animal.method' is it just good practice or there is a much more important cause?

Comment: Oh thanks for reminding me! hahaha my professor already pointed that out to me

Comment: `super` is useful for a bunch of different things, but mostly it is a necessary step in initialising a subclass. When you call `super` like that, it picks up the object and does the necessary superclass init as well as anything defined in your subclass init - in this example when you call super().__init__(name) it sets self._name for your fish - the way you were doing it you haven't specified self in the call to Animal, so it doesn't know where to store the name - self is the object (if `a = Fish('nemo')` then self is the object's alias for `a`)

Comment: `super().method()` is better than just calling `Animal.method()` because you may change the inheritance hierarchy later.

Answer (score 2):

You had some missunderstoods in calling the init function of the parent class. As well as some other things.

```py
class Animal:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self._name = name

    def sound(self):
        raise NotImplementedError("You have not overridden my sound yet!")

    def move(self):
        raise NotImplementedError("You have not overridden my movement yet!")

    def habitat(self):
        raise NotImplementedError("You have not overridden my habitat yet!")


class Fish(Animal):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super(Fish, self).__init__(name)
    def sound(self):
        return f'{self._name} says blub blub'
    def movement(self):
        return f'{self._name} is swimming'
    def habitat(self):
        return f'{self._name} is an Aquatic Animal'

a=Fish('nemo')
print(a.sound())
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but if I may ask, I know that super() calls the inherited class. So what happens if I defined something inside super() like what you did here, what does this do? Also, I don't understand why it is better to call super() rather than just calling 'Animal.method' is it just good practice or there is a much more important cause?

Comment: have a look at this:
https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/super/working-python-super-function

Comment: Now that you have changed `Fish` to use `self._name` (a good move in my opinion), this means that the whole of the `__init__()` method in `Fish` is redundant and can be removed

Comment: That is completely true haha